# How to repeat a function in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need a repeating function in react. I have an array of words and an element which I want to change every 2 seconds to the following item of the array and again and again. If the array ends, start over. I tried this code:

```
  const words = ['Hi', 'Gutten Tag', 'Hola', 'Bonjour']
  const [word, updateWord] = useState(0) // The word would be accessible at words[word] 

  function handleLoop() {
    if (word === words.length - 1) {
      updateWord(0)
    }
    else {
      updateWord(word + 1)
    }
    setTimeout(handleLoop(), 2000)
  }
```

But react thinks that it will cause an infinite loop.
[image: The error]

How should I fix it?

Comment: bruh, you need to do `setTimeout(handleLoop, 2000)` not `setTimeout(handleLoop(), 2000)`. You are calling the function right there in setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use useEffect hook

You can have the `useEffect` hook triggered after every 2 seconds by updating the `word` and specifying it in the dependency list.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// keep words in a separate constants.js file
// if it's a constant and not consumed from an API
const words = ["Hi", "Gutten Tag", "Hola", "Bonjour"];

const App = () => {
  // maintain word as a local state
  const [word, updateWord] = useState(0);

  // hook will be triggerd every time word
  // gets updated after every 2000ms
  useEffect(() => {
    let nextWord;

    // logic stays the same
    if (word === words.length - 1) {
      nextWord = 0;
    } else {
      nextWord = word + 1;
    }

    // update the word
    setTimeout(() => updateWord(nextWord), 2000);
  }, [word]);

  return (
    <p>{words[word]}</p>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stackoverflow occurs](http://Stack%20overflow)

**Fix:**

```
 const words = ['Hi', 'Gutten Tag', 'Hola', 'Bonjour']
 const [word, updateWord] = useState(0) // The word would be accessible at words[word] 

 function handleLoop() {
   if (word === words.length - 1) {
     updateWord(0)
   }
   else {
     updateWord(word + 1)
   }
 }

 setInterval(handleLoop, 2000)
```

Comment: Hey there, try explaining your answer a bit instead of posting "only-code" replies, it would make your answer more readable and provide more context to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think setInterval is better way, here

```
const words = ['Hi', 'Gutten Tag', 'Hola', 'Bonjour']
const [word, updateWord] = useState(0) // The word would be accessible at words[word] 

let handleLoop = function() {
    if (word === words.length) {
      updateWord(0)
    }
    else {
      updateWord(word + 1)
    }
    console.log(words[word])
  }

 setInterval(handleLoop, 2000)
```

Comment: This worked for the first 3 times, then started doing this glitching: https://i.imgur.com/fH1Nvc5.gif

Answer (score -1):

```
function countDown(fromNumber) {
    console.log(fromNumber);

    let nextNumber = fromNumber - 1;

    if (nextNumber > 0) {
        countDown(nextNumber);
    }
}
countDown(3);
```

```js
function countDown(fromNumber) {
    console.log(fromNumber);

    let nextNumber = fromNumber - 1;

    if (nextNumber > 0) {
        countDown(nextNumber);
    }
}
countDown(3);
```

Comment: I suggest adding some comments that will explain your answer.

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information